# Can I do big oh of 1 lookups on short-hand arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

This is a question on ability of PHP to use arrays in the way I want.

Consider arrays below:

```
1) array(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70);  //aka "shorthand"

2) array(10 => 1, 20 => 1, 30 => 1, 40 => 1, 50 => 1, 60 => 1, 70 => 1);
```

For my purposes they both have the same numbers essentially, just represented differently.

Naturally, I prefer the first way, as it lists just the numbers I need.  It also makes more sense to me as my values are the numbers that I want to operate on.  In #2 the values are all 1s, and if I need to loop through my "values of interest", I actually need to loop through array keys.  In my legacy code however my arrays are a tad longer and tend to use function `in_array`, which has big oh of N.  I needed a faster lookup on values of the array, so I rewrote the array as in way #2 and used function `array_key_exists`, which I presume is big oh of 1.  Due to large codebase I am basically ending up with two array representations that require different code to work on them.  And I don't like that.

I prefer to write my arrays as in #1...  So in some ideal world I could write arrays as in #1 but have big oh of 1 lookup on them, when I need to check whether a value exists in array.
Is there such a way?  If not, what is the next best thing?

Update: using array flip option:

```
3) if (in_array(10, [10,20,30,40,50,60,70])) {}

4) if (array_key_exists(10, array_flip([10,20,30,40,50,60,70]))) {}
```

Comment: `array_flip([10,20,30,40,50,60,70])` is the simplest way to have your items as keys ;)

Comment: see my update.. not sure if that will aid in reducing big oh, if I am only doing a single lookup.  But it keeps my shorthand array representation.  And if I am doing multiple lookups, yes that will help

Answer (score 0):

You can use hashes/dictionaries to achieve a theoretical O(1) speed. Your suggestion #2 is capable of doing that.

Hashes/dictionaries are O(1) best case and average case, O(N) in worst case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are bonded to the use of arrays, the answer to your question depends on whether the array's content is changed frequently or not.

**Array doesn't change frequently**

If the array is not changed frequently, you could use the function `array_flip` once, in order to make a searchable version of your array and keep it for as long as possible.

In this way you have once an operation that is O(n), and every time you search you have operations that are near to O(1), using `array_key_exists`.

**Array changes frequently**

In this case to use `in_array`, wich is O(n), is almost equivalent to (if not better than) using `array_flip` with `array_key_exists`, since `array_flip` is O(n) itself and `array_key_exists` is O(1) at best, and you would have to perform both of them everytime.

It would be an interesting solution to keep the array sorted, and then use an optimized search algorithm, that, with an ordered array would be at worst O(log n).
Binary search could be a good search algorithm for that purpose:

```
function binarySearch($needle, $array)
{
 $start = 0;
 $end = count($array) - 1;

 while ($start <= $end) {
  $middle = (int) ($start + ($end - $start) / 2);
  if ($needle < $array[$middle]) {
   $end = $middle - 1;
  } else if ($needle > $array[$middle]) {
   $start = $middle + 1;
  } else {
   return $needle;
  }
 }

 return false;
}
```

This binary search sample is taken from [here](http://themessycode.blogspot.it/2013/08/php-performance-built-in-arraysearch-vs.html).

To keep the array sorted you would have to sort it the first time (`sort` function should be fine for that, since you should use it once), and then add new items splitting the array where the element should be placed, put the element at the end of the first part of the array and merge the arrays back.

This would make the array maintainance more expensive, but would improve search performance.